# Task Scheduler with ps1 script outputs empty file

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, windows-task-scheduler

Running a ps1 independently works fine, however when I schedule via Task Scheduler, the task runs and outputs a 0 byte csv file.

I believe I have the scheduled task setup correctly, no quotes in Start In - program is set to powershell.exe, arguments are set to -execution policy bypass -file "C:\Temp\file.ps1"

```
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $MyCredential -Tenant ##########################
$dteshort = (get-date).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
$objectIDs = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId ######### | Select-Object objectid,displayname,mail

$groups = foreach ($objectID in $objectids) {
    $user = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $objectid.ObjectId
    Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $objectID.ObjectId | Where-Object { $_.displayname -like '*PartOfGroupName*' } | 
    Select-Object @{Name = 'email'; Expression = {$user.mail}}, displayname
}
#

$groups | Export-Csv -Path "D:\LocalPathToFileExport\PBI\PBI_Licenses_AsOf_$dteshort.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

After adding start/stop transcript

```
    
    ConvertTo-SecureString : Key not valid for use in specified state.

At C:\PSScripts\PowerBI HR Partner.ps1:5 char:143
+ ... et-Content $secUser), (Get-Content $SecFile | ConvertTo-SecureString)
+                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], CryptographicException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
ImportSecureString_InvalidArgument_CryptographicError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand
ConvertTo-SecureString : Key not valid for use in specified state.

At C:\PSScripts\PowerBI HR Partner.ps1:5 char:143
+ ... et-Content $secUser), (Get-Content $SecFile | ConvertTo-SecureString)
+                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], CryptographicExcepti
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ImportSecureString_InvalidArgument_CryptographicError,Microsoft.Pow
   erShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand
```

I thought this would work for authenticating to Azure AD, it does when ran manually.  The password is exported from Get-Credential / ConvertFrom-SecureString and saved in password.txt

```
$SecFile = "C:\AzureAD\Password.txt"
$SecUser = "C:\AzureAD\UserName.txt"
$MyCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential  -ArgumentList (Get-Content $secUser), (Get-Content $SecFile | ConvertTo-SecureString)
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $MyCredential -Tenant ########
```

After messing around with this, the ConvertTo-SecureString wasn't working as I expected and had to go another route to authenticate to Azure.

It's working now, thanks all for the help diagnosing this.

Comment: What account is this running under for the scheduled task? Does that account have access to query AD?

Comment: I've seen this before when the scipt was running as 32-bit Powershell rather than 64-bit, one of the modules only supported one bitness. It's also highly likely to be a permissions issues as @TheMadTechnician mentioned. You'll likely narrow down the issue by adding `Start-Transcript -path D:\LocalPathToFileExport\PBI\TranscriptScriptLog.txt` to the start of your script and `Stop-Transcript` to the bottom. You should write more progress out to console, print out dteshort, objectIDs, groups as you proceed through the script - output == diagnostic evidence == problem solved.

Comment: I would also add a `Try{ <#code here #> }catch{ write $_.Exception.Message }` wrapped around everything with `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` above the try catch. You might have the `AzureAD` module added to your PoSh profile, but the account the task is running as doesn't have the module available - you should check the module exists.

Comment: And after adding start/stop transcript (thank you for that!) I see the connect-azuread isn't working as it does when ran manually.  I'll post the error here shortly.

Comment: Also - the account running this is (for now) local admin.

Comment: Can you connect to azure using other applications?  Latest version of azure requires OAUTH for authentication.  It depends on how the azure is configured and version.  If another application is working I would check the authentication in working app.